# Display all users except for the assigned ones. Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a screen where **admin** adds topics, db name is **`chat_topics`** **(id, title, status)** then in edit topic screen, there are two lists with available users and assigned users.

When **admins** assigns users it saves in a pivot table, **`chat_topic_user`** **(chat_topic_id, users_id)**

Now, one user can be assign to many topics. I am able to assign users to topics, then in edit screen I am able to display all the assigned users for that specific topic.

Problem comes when I assign a specific user it even shows in available users which should not display, for example if **userA** is assigned to **TopicA** then for **TopicA** edit screen it shouldn't display **userA** in available users, right.
But **userA** should be displayed on **TopicB** edit edit screen.

I hope I am clear enough to explain the problem.

Code to display all available users:

```
 User::with('chat_topics')->get()
```

(if **userA** is assigned to **TopicA**, so **userA** shouldn't be displayed in available users, but it should be displayed for **TopicB** available list)

**Code to display only assigned users on specific topic**

```
User::has('chat_topics')->whereHas('chat_topics', function ($query) use ($topic_id) { $query->where('id', $topic_id); })->get();
```

**I want something like this:**

> **TOPIC A EDIT SCREEN**
>   -   **Assigned Users**
>   user a
>   user b
>   **Available Users**
>   empty (if only two users in db)
>
> **TOPIC B EDIT SCREEN**
>   -   **Assigned Users**
>   empty
>   **Available Users**
>   user a
>   user b

**Currently it displays like this:**

> **TOPIC A EDIT SCREEN**
>   -   **Assigned Users**
>   user a
>   user b
>   -   **Available Users**
>   user a
>   user b

Its duplicating, as one cant be assigned more than once for same topic.

Thanks in advance. would really appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
$assignedUsers = User::has('chat_topics')->whereHas('chat_topics', function ($query) use ($topic_id) { $query->where('id', $topic_id); })->get();

// get the list of assigned userIds
$assignedIds = $assignedUsers->pluck('id');

// get the list of available user excerpt users in $assignedUsers
$availableUsers =  User::with('chat_topics')->whereNotIn('id', $assignedIds)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the above code somehow gave me some array_map error msg, but your answer directed me towards right way. thanks a lot :D here is what i did,

        $assigned = User::has('chat_topics')
            ->whereHas('chat_topics', function ($query) use ($topic_id) {
                $query->where('id', $topic_id);
            })->pluck('id');


        return  User::whereNotIn('id', $assigned)->get();

Comment: @HashaamAhmed It will not work if you use PHP 5.x. I have updated my answer. Hope it will work :D

Comment: Oh ok. yeap saw the updated answer. much appreciated :)